# How organize project based on parsing scripts and inserting data to postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, queue, project-organization

I have a few questions about my logic on project. My project based on scripts which parse data from a thousand's websites(separate script for website). Actually I have ~40 scripts, but I wanna organize it for big scale data in future. After scraping, scripts have a method 'insert_data' which insert data (list of dictionaries) to my POSTGRESQL database. In scripts to get data I use libraries: requests, urllib, sometimes selenium (pages with JS) and BeautifulSoup4 to parse downloaded data. Bellow logic of my scripts:

```
class Main():
# initialize variables

def __init__():

def get_url(self, url):
    requests.get(url)
    return soup(url)

# data_insert is list of dicts
def insert_data(self, data_insert):
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO table1 (url, title, etc...) VALUES (% (url)s, %(title)s, data_insert)

def __main__(self):
    # 1 looping
    for auction in auctions:
        list_auctions.append(get_href_auction)

    # 2 looping
    for row in list_auctions:
        get_url(row)
        grab some data
        record = {"var1":"value", "var2":"value" etc}
        final_list.append(record)

    # after 2 looping insert data to POSTGRESQL
    insert_data(final_list)
```

In database I have table to every website and table 'data_all'. Scripts inserting data into table per website and I have trigger after insert which loading data from these tables to main table 'data_all'. Bellow code of my trigger's:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_data_to_main_table
  AFTER INSERT
  ON data_table1
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_data_to_main_table();

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_insert_data_to_main_table
  AFTER INSERT
  ON data_table2
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_data_to_main_table();
```

etc... for all my tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_data_to_main_table()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO data_all
 SELECT t1.*
 FROM data_table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN data_all d ON d.url = t1.url
 WHERE d.url IS NULL
 UNION
 SELECT t2.*
 FROM data_table2 t2
 LEFT JOIN data_all d ON d.url = t2.url
 WHERE d.url IS NULL;
 RETURN NULL;
 END;
 SELECT t3.*
 FROM data_table3 t3
```

etc... for all my tables.

This function provides me ignore duplicates of urls (which are UNIQUE per row) in main table 'data_all'.

1. Is a good logic for scraping scripts? For pages without JS is working fine (fast). Sometimes I have only 1 loop to grab some data from main page (without iterate for auction).
2. Is a good way insert data in this way? In future I have to create a main script with queue of scraping scripts
3. How to secure the main script so that in the event of an error he would return a message to me and continue working?
4. I've recently read about multiprocessing. Is it a good idea to use it in this project to increase efficiency?
5. Somebody have better idea to grab data from JS pages? I find solution based on request.post. It's only alternative to selenium in python?

Very thanks for read post to end and hope you can help me. Regards :)

Answer (score 0):

you can speed up selenium pages by strategically stop loading a page once you get the data you need or certain item shows up.
as far as db advise, i was using simpledb, but last i used it had weird issue with multithreading, so i wrote my own local simple DB based on dictionaries and json, i use queue.queue() q.get() as a hack to block and then release sections of my db code, so i can use in multiple threads

i advise you to put proper wait() functions between queries to the same domain out of respect for all other data aggregators out there, if you abuse a website, they will make it harder for everyone else. figure out a good logic based on IP, cookies, and url/domain names that skip or wait .
i wrote my own IP manager to handle this, i even have minimum wait times for urls, even though i think most websites check by domain not url
basically i check ip,domain,and specific url in a database, to see whether wait X amount of seconds based on minimum defaults. all http requests go through my ipmanager before submitting the requests

if you're multithreading or multiprocessing, u want to divide up functions that take the most time to complete, which is usually http requests..
db input wait time is minimal, i dont seperate that by different threads, i just only let certain operations happen one thread at a time like 'update' functions within the db. read functons dont have a lock

here's a class called QStack, basically I add requests to the stack
which returns an ID, i use this ID in my other code to process the response
I can provide some more code insight, if you want to team up, i was trying to figure out why i have some proxy connect issues lately, i tried turning verify to false and i read some weird stuff in urllib3 in requests

```
class QStack:

def getproxy(self,fp=0):
    #print 'wait for queue'
    #z=self.qq.get()
    while True:
        if fp:
            p=self.fpxo.get()
        else:
            p=self.pxo.get()
        ipo=ip(p)

        #print 'looking for ip'
        if ipo not in self.inuse:
            self.inuse.append(ipo)
            break
        time.sleep(1)

    #print 'put bob in queue'
    #self.qq.put('bob')
    return p


def start(self):
    self.ts1=time.time()
    self.qc=0
    self.hari2=1
    t = threading.Thread(
    target=self.manage_threads
            )
    t.start()




def stop(self):
    self.hari2=0

def __init__(self,ipm,pxo,
      mthreads=1,fpxo=None):

    self.fpxo=fpxo
    self.hari=1
    self.mthreads=mthreads
    self.ipm=ipm
    self.pxo=pxo

    self.rqs = Queue.Queue()
    self.rps = Queue.Queue()

    self.b = Queue.Queue()
    self.c = Queue.Queue()
    self.c.put('bob')
    self.b.put('bob')
    self.inuse=[]
    self.mc=-1
    self.athreads=0

    self.idc=-1
    self.ct=0

def manage_threads(self):
    while self.hari2:
        if self.athreads<self.mthreads:
            t = threading.Thread(
                target=self.do
            )
            t.start()
            #print 'added thread'*20
        #print 'current threads'*20,self.athreads
        time.sleep(1)

def do(self):
    if self.rqs.empty():
        return -1

    self.athreads+=1
    q=self.rqs.get()
    s = http_incognito(self.ipm)
    s.timeout=self.pxo.timeout
    hari = True

    while hari:
        #print 'hi'
        if q.ua == 'auto':
            s.incognito()
        else:
            s.useragent=q.ua

        s.cookies=q.cookies
        s.referer = q.ref

        fp=0
        self.mc+=1
        if self.mc >= self.mthreads:
            self.mc=0
            fp=1

        p = self.getproxy(fp)
        ipo=ip(p)

        q.p=p
        q.fp=fp
        #print'lalaalla'

        try:


            then=time.time()
            a=s.get(q.url,proxy=p)
            hari=0
            #print 'done'
            #ff=random.choice(xrange(1,10))
            #print 'sleep',ff
            #time.sleep(ff)


            #print'did reqeust'
        except Exception as e:
            print 'HTTP ERROR'
            print str(e)
            self.inuse.remove(ipo)

            if fp:
                self.fpxo.update(p,0)
            else:
                self.pxo.update(p,0)
            self.athreads-=1
            continue


        q.rp=a
        #print 'okayyyy'

        #no blank response
        if not q.rp:
            print 'blank response'*20
            print q.url,q.p


            if fp:
                self.fpxo.update(p,0)
            else:
                self.pxo.update(p,0)

            hari=1
            self.inuse.remove(ipo)
            continue

        if not q.rcheck(q.v()):
            print 'NONONONONONO'

            if fp:
                self.fpxo.update(p,0)
            else:
                self.pxo.update(p,0)


            print 'robot', p
            self.inuse.remove(ipo)
            hari=1
            self.athreads-=1
            continue
        #print 'horehorehore'
        #print 'passed rcheck'

    #print 'lalala'
    self.rps.put(q)
    del s  #remove
    z= q.id


    self.inuse.remove(ipo)
    self.athreads-=1
    return z

def readd(self,q):
    self.rqs.put(
       q)

def add(self,
 url,
 ref=None,
 cookies=None,
 ua='auto',
 headers=None,
 rcheck=None):





    a=self.b.get()


    self.ct +=1

    q = QQuery(url,
        ref,cookies,
         ua,
         headers,
          rcheck=rcheck)

    self.idc += 1
    q.id=self.idc
    self.rqs.put(
       q)


    self.b.put('fred')
    return q.id


def get(self,ide=None):
    a=self.c.get()

    q = self.rps.get()
    if ide != None:
        while q.id != ide:
            self.rps.put(q)
            q=self.rps.get()

    self.c.put('bob')
    return q
```

its used like this:

```
qinfo={}
pxo=proxymanager()
ipm=ipmanager()
fpxo=myip()

qs=QStack(10,pxo,ipm,fpxo)
for u in urllist:
    ide = qs.add(u)
    qinfo[ide]='type, more info'
qs.start()


while True:
    q=qs.get() 
    info=qinfo[q.id]
    #process query in different ways
    #based on info, id, etc
    find more urls
     qs.add(u)
```